How to build or incorporate part of AOSP apps into your app?
I want to reuse (parts of) the AOSP DeskClock app in my app. The sources can be found in Google's repository but it doesn't come as a Gradle project.
How to incorporate it into an app, for example as a library module, and build it?
Related questions and answers:

How to download Source code from Android Google Source With Gradle files
How to build AOSP app?
How to compile DeskClock of android4.3 sourcecode


As described in this answer, the AOSP apps don't come as a gradle project, but are usually compiled in a system build (where they also have access to other dependencies and resources).
So building the source as part of a gradle project is not straight-forward, some adaptions are necessary.
I successfully got a subset of DeskClock (e.g. without Timer, Stopwatch and some further UI parts) to compile with gradle with the following steps:

Clone the AOSP code
In a new or existing AndroidStudio/Gradle project, create a new library module (if you want to use it as part of another app, otherwise create an app project)

Find information for minSdk etc. in the AOSP code's AndroidManifest.xml


Adapt the library's AndroidManifest.xml according to the AOSP code's AndroidManifest.xml (it should not necessarily be the same)
Copy the classes/packages/resources from the AOSP code you need to your library module under src/main/ (into the respective subdirectories java, res etc.)
Try to compile and repeatedly add the missing source files referenced from the copied sources
Add missing library dependencies; they can be detected by unresolved imports, e.g. those of androix libraries
Fix the sources for references which do not work in a normal app/library context:

Add the following to build.gradle.kts if the code references the BuildConfig class:
buildFeatures {
    buildConfig = true
}


Change BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID to BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME and set android { namespace = <packgae name> } accordingly in build.gradle (in case you are using a library module)
(optional) Remove unused resources with the corresponding inspection
Fix unresolved references to resource values R.xxx

Some are Android platform resources, change the reference to android.R.xxx
Some are from libraries, e.g. androidx.preference.R.attr.dropdownPreferenceStyle


Change some const val which refer to resources but which fail to compile because they are not considered constant by removing the const modifier


Add activities, permissions etc. to your app's AndroidManifest.xml, depending on what you use from the library module

Specific for DeskClock:

You might have to introduce new Build.VERSION.SDK_INT checks in ClockContract, e.g. I needed to replace a usage of isOOrLater because it actually required O_MR1:
val isOMR1OrLater: Boolean
      get() = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1



